# Вызов переменной в Python

Tags: python, переменные

Есть переменная name, в которай записан текст, к примеру "n", как вызвать переменную название которой является текст в переменной name?

Comment: это такое решение какой-то задачи или чтобы просто знать?

Comment: Для задачи, какой не могу сказать

Comment: Смотрите `eval(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def some_func():
    print('hello')


name = 'some_func'

globals()[name]()
```