# Вызов Python функции в зависимости от переданного аргумент при вызове скрипта

Tags: python

Есть скрипт с несколькими функциями:

```
  def a():
    pass

  def b():
    pass 

  def c():
    pass
```

Которые должны запускаться в зависимости от переданного при запуске скрипта аргумента. Можно создать множество `if` условий:

```
if args.function == "a":
    a()
elif args.function == "b":
    b()
elif args.function == "c":
    c()
```

Но может быть есть более изящный способ реализовать это? Спасибо.

Я знаю о существовании похожего вопроса:
[Вызов переменной в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/881470/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-python)

Но там только один вариант, который не подходит всегда. Возможно есть ещё какие-то варианты.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вызов переменной в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/881470/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2-python)

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант - словарь

```
action = {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c}

result = action[sys.argv[1]]()
```

Comment: Нельзя ли в 
parser.add_argument функции указать что при передаче этого аргумента выполнять функцию с названием переданного аргумента?

Comment: Не совсем понял о чем речь, но мне кажется, если ты точно знаешь название функции, которую нужно выполнить, то ты как то неправильно строишь твое приложение, раз приходиться восстанавливать функцию из строки с ее названием. Тут можно много костылей придумать, например globals()['a']() но я бы посоветовал пересмотреть код, и найти другой подход, что бы не приходилось восстанавливать имя функции из строки.

Comment: Почему же, иногда удобнее брать из строки. Допустим приложение строит график тригонометрических функций. Намного проще взять имя функции из параметра, чем писать код для каждого варианта (синус, косинус и т.д.). Запустил ``my_graph.py sin`` и она сама вызывает ``math.sin`` без явного указания.

Comment: Приложение правильное думаю. Оно в зависимости от переданного имени сервиса Amazon (например Ec2) разведует все запущенные инстансы и возвращает их список. Сервис может быть любой, но способы разведки от сервиса к сервису различаются, поэтому для каждого сервиса нужна своя разведовательная функция.

Comment: Я просто не очень могу понять задачу, можешь примерный псевдокод набросать, как тебе хотелось бы, что оно работало?

Comment: Наверное с globals().get('a') вариант подойдёт, спасибо. Задача простая, разведка сервисов в амазоне, например для "EC2" - вернуть список инстансов, для "ELB" вернуть списко лоадбалансеров. Очевидно что каждый разведуется по-разному. Для каждого - своя функция. И понял что все сводится к тому что если вызвали скрипт с аргументом "EC2" то разведовать надо EC2 и т.д.

Понятна задача?

Comment: В идеале это был бы простой вызов (переменная с именем сервиса (которой соответствует имя функции) + ()):
args.service()

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете это сделать, используя модуль `argparse`. Тогда использование будет по аналогии с `git commit` или `git config`... и т.д.

Собственно код:

```
import argparse


# функции "обработчики"

def run_service1():
    print("Run service1 now")


def run_service2():
    print("Run service2 now")


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()


service1 = subparsers.add_parser('service1')
service1.set_defaults(func=run_service1)  # задаем функцию по умолчанию для service1

service2 = subparsers.add_parser('service2')
service2.set_defaults(func=run_service2)  # задаем функцию по умолчанию для service2

args = parser.parse_args()
args.func()  # вызываем функцию по умолчанию
```

Сохранив все это дело в файлик и запустив с указанными параметрами получаем:

```
D:\>test.py service1
Run service1 now

D:\>test.py service2
Run service2 now
```

Из вывода видно, что выводятся строки из функций-обработчиков.

Кроме этого, само собой разумеется, Вы вольны добавить в парсер любые другие необходимые Вам параметры.